# Validating a Date String in Python

Tags: python

I have a list called "page" that looks something like this:

```
'1/1/2015 ~ Some text here'
'9/30/2015 ~ more text here'
'12/12/2015 ~ even more text'
'1. ~ bad text here'
```

What I want to do is to go through each one using partition to grab the date string from the front, and if the string is not a date, then perform some action.  If it is, just move to the next one.

I just can't seem to get the validation of the date to work; any suggestions?

Comment: *"can't seem to get this just right"* - so what do have now, and what precisely is the problem with it?

Comment: As a jumping-off point, please provide the code of the last attempt you made.

Comment: Look at [`dateutil.parser.parse()`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse). You'll still need to extract what you think is the date (maybe with `r'\S+(?=\s~)'`).

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following. Hope it helps.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import datetime

def validate(date_text):
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(date_text, '%d/%m/%Y')
        print("Date format correct")
    except ValueError:
        print("date format incorrect")

validate('31/12/2015')
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import datetime

my_list = ['1/1/2015 ~ Some text here', '9/30/2015 ~ more text here', '12/12/2015 ~ even more text', '1. ~ bad text here']

for x in my_list:
    try:
        date = x.split(' ~')[0]
        datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y')
    except:
        print 'not a valid date...do something'
```